# How to add dot to a number - YYYYMM to YYYY.MM

Tags: r, date

I have the problem following, I have a lot of numbers:

```
x <- c(200103, 200106,200109)
```

Actually those are dates and I want them in format 2001.03, 2001.06, 2001.09 etc., i.e. I want to add dot after four first numbers. Is there any simple way how can we do that in r?

Comment: Try `sub('([0-9]{4})(.*)$', '\\1\\.\\2', '200103')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture data in two groups. 1st 4 characters and next 2 and add `"."` in between them.

```
x <- c(200103, 200106,200109)
sub('(.{4})(.{2})', '\\1.\\2', x)
#[1] "2001.03" "2001.06" "2001.09"
```

The standard way would be to convert to date and use `format` to get data in required format.

```
format(as.Date(paste0(x, 1), '%Y%m%d'), '%Y.%m')
```

Comment: Great! Does the R now recognize vector x as a date or as a character ? If character what has to be done to change it class to date ? ;))

Comment: the output is still a character. To change it to class date you need all 3 i.e date, month and year which is output of `as.Date(paste0(x, 1), '%Y%m%d')`

Answer (score 1):

We could convert to `yearmon` class and then use `format`

```
library(zoo)
format(as.yearmon(as.character(x), "%Y%m"), "%Y.%m")
#[1] "2001.03" "2001.06" "2001.09"
```